# Facebook Application-Uncaught OAuthException:

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

my aplication is work fine but there is one problem. when someone try to use my application he/she gets this error. other problem is after allowing the app it doesnt redirect anywhere, you have to resresf page. after allow and refreshing you can use app.

my allow code: fb:login-button perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,offline_access">

you can check my app page: https://apps.facebook.com/denemeapicik/

error:

Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token: User 1000abc has not authorized application 144171878989963. thrown in /home/xyzz/facebook.php on line 560

ı try this but it doesnt work:

```
$params = array(
'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require_once("facebook.php");
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '***',
    'secret' => '***',
  'scope'  => 'manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream,user_photos'
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```